# Use variable with regex to find data in mongodb (Meteor app)

Tags: regex, mongodb, meteor

I need to get data from Mongodb that in dependence of what I am searching. In the next two examples it work fine:
//example 1;

```
var variable = "car"; Items.find({"description": variable}).fetch();
```

//example2;

```
Items.find({"description": /.*car.*/}).fetch();
```

but, when I want to combine variable with regex in MongoDB query it returns nothing, what am I doing wrong:

```
Items.find({"description": /.*variable.*/}).fetch();
Items.find({"description": "/.*"+variable+".*/"}).fetch();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Indeed. You may not be realizing that `"/"` is not the same as `/` and the latter does not have a semantics for concatenation (like `+` for strings) as afar as I know of (but I might be wrong). The latter syntax is an inline/shorthand constructor for the `RegExp` class. That said it is easy to fix, just create the regex explicitly using `new RegExp`.

In your case, however, I would recommend to use mongodb's `$regex` construct:

```
Items.find({"description": {$regex: ".*" + variable + ".*"}}).fetch();
```

For more details see the [documentation on `$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

Answer (score 6):

And if you need it to be case-insensitive then you should use regex like this:

```
new RegExp(".*"+keyword+".*", "i")
```

Answer (score 3):

The Answer is each keyword by search

```
Items.find({"description": {
                        '$regex': new RegExp(variable, "i")
                    }}).fetch();
```